# Broken url in tutorial

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This page
http://wiki.ros.org/actionlib_tutorials/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20Simple%20Action%20Server%20using%20the%20Execute%20Callback%20%28Python%29

has a broken link to
http://www.ros.org/doc/api/actionlib_tutorials/html/msg/FibonacciAction.html

named "Fibonacci action"

Edit: When I looked yesterday, the C++ page for the same tutorial had the same problem with the same link.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/207632/broken-url-in-tutorial/) by [korkor](https://answers.ros.org/users/22243/korkor/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2015-04-22

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Naman](https://answers.ros.org/users/11186/naman/) on 2015-04-22**:
The correct link : http://docs.ros.org/api/actionlib_tutorials/html/classFibonacciAction.html

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2015-04-23**:
That is not the correct link; it links to a C++ class; not the generated docs for Fibonacci.action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This looks like a bug in the auto-generation of docs for the actionlib_tutorials; I've reported it: https://github.com/ros/common_tutorials/issues/11

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2015-04-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3